# Express router.route: 404 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The first route is working fine, but I get a 404 when I send a request for the second route.

Sending a GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/posts/ returns:

```
  {
    message: "TODO return all posts"
  }
```

But sending a GET request to http://localhost:3000/api/posts/1234 returns:

```
404
Error: Not Found
```

Am I missing something?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.route('/posts')
  //returns all posts
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.send({message: 'TODO return all posts'});
  })

  .post(function(req, res) {
      res.send({message: 'TODO Create a new post'});
  });

router.route('/posts/:id')
  //returns a particular post
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.send({message: 'TODO return post with ID ' + req.params.id})
  })

  //update existing post
  .put(function(req, res) {
    res.send({message: 'TODO modify post with ID ' + req.params.id})
  })

  //delete existing post
  .delete(function(req, res) {
    res.send({message: 'TODO delete post with ID ' + req.params.id})
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a typo, but wouldn't the URL be `localhost:3000/posts/1234`, not `localhost:3000/index/posts/1234`?

Comment: I'm just using index as a router in my app.js file.

    var index = require('./routes/index');
    app.use('/index', index);

Comment: Ok, looking further, I don't see the `router.route('/route').get().put().delete()` in the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) as chainable. I see examples of the following type:

```router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})```

To chain like you are doing above, it looks like you need to use `app.route()`.